# I have issue with PHP in_array

Tags: php

|1||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10||11||12||13||14||15|

form this how do I check |10| is available on the above array?
I use in_array also I am not familiar with the array.
I need to print

```
if (|10|) {
 echo hello!
};
```

Comment: What array? Show the code. There isn't any array in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your array as string then

```
$str="|1||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10||11||12||13||14||15|";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $array);
if(in_array(10,$array[0])){
echo "found";
}else{
echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: this is perfect 

how do I group in the array, if the array result is the same to avoid duplicate results?

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the string you get from your db into an array, apply 'array_filter' to remove empty values, and then use 'in_array' to see if it exists.

```
$db_string = "|1||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10||11||12||13||14||15|";
$array = array_filter(explode("|", $db_string)); 

var_dump($array);

if(in_array(10,$array)){
  echo "exists";
}
```

Comment: @HishamIsmail Welcome :) please mark as correct answer if it solved your use case

Comment: this is perfect 

how do I group in the array, if the array result is the same to avoid duplicate results?

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_string = "|1||3||1||5||1||3||8||1||10||2|2||13||2||15|";
$array = array_filter(explode("|", $db_string)); 

 if(in_array("1", $array)){
  echo"<li>
         <a href="#">Honeymoon Packages</a>
       </li>";
  }
```

RESULT is Coming

```
* Honeymoon Packages
* Honeymoon Packages
* Honeymoon Packages
* Honeymoon Packages
```

because in array 1 is there 4 time, how do I group this in array and print result one time without duplicate?